# Help with Graphics3D code -- how to outline a point?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I am attempting to use the following set of code

```
Show[
 VectorPlot3D[
  {x (1 - x) - x*y, y (1 - y) + x*y - y*z, z (1 - z) + y*z},
  {x, 0, 1.2}, {y, 0, 1.2}, {z, 0, 1.2},
  Axes -> True,
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
  VectorColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
  VectorPoints -> 5,
  VectorScale -> {0.03, .7, None},
  VectorStyle ->
   Graphics[
    {EdgeForm[Black], Rectangle[{-2, -.2}, {0, .2}], 
     Polygon[{{0, .5}, {Sqrt[3], 0}, {0, -.5}}]}
    ]
  ],
 Graphics3D[{
   PointSize[0.05],
   Point[{0, 0, 0}],
   EdgeForm[Black],
   FaceForm[Red]
   }]
 ]
```

In order to plot a three dimensional vector field (which looks exactly the way I want it to with no issues, so no problems with the first half) in order to get a phase space diagram for a system of ODEs.

Now, I'd also like to plot the equilibrium points of the system on the point, so I started with the origin. I would like the points to be red with a black outline, so they look sort of thematically consistent with the vectors in the plot (I also think an outline really helps to improve the readability on a 3D plot).

However, using `EdgeForm` and `FaceForm` isn't working for me, which according to the documentation is because they do not work for Point objects but instead for polygons.

So, my question is, is there a way to give the point a solid black outline? Or will I have to define the point in another way?

Comment: "will I have to define the point in another way?" - yes; use `Disk[]` with a "tiny" radius and then use `EdgeForm[]` to get your desired style.

Comment: @J.M.isslightlypensive Looking at the Documentation, Graphics3D does not accept `Disk[]` as a primitive. How do I do this? Would you mind posting an answer showing how this would work?

Comment: Hmm, it looks like I missed the "3D" part of your question. Perhaps an approximation with `CirclePoints[]` could be done. The problem with this is figuring how to properly orient the flat disks so that they are directly facing you from the current `ViewPoint` setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Text` with `\[EmptyCircle]` and `\[FilledCircle]`:

```
Show[VectorPlot3D[{x (1 - x) - x*y, y (1 - y) + x*y - y*z, 
   z (1 - z) + y*z}, {x, 0, 1.2}, {y, 0, 1.2}, {z, 0, 1.2}, 
  Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
  VectorColorFunction -> "Rainbow", VectorPoints -> 5, 
  VectorScale -> {0.03, .7, None}, 
  VectorStyle -> Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Rectangle[{-2, -.2}, {0, .2}], 
     Polygon[{{0, .5}, {Sqrt[3], 0}, {0, -.5}}]}]], 
 Graphics3D[{Text[Style["\[FilledCircle]",  Yellow, FontSize -> Scaled[.05]], {0, 0, 0}], 
  Text[Style["\[EmptyCircle]", Black, FontSize -> Scaled[.05]], {0, 0, 0}]}]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use two `Point`s with slightly different sizes:

```
Show[VectorPlot3D[{x (1 - x) - x*y, y (1 - y) + x*y - y*z, 
   z (1 - z) + y*z}, {x, 0, 1.2}, {y, 0, 1.2}, {z, 0, 1.2}, 
  Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
  VectorColorFunction -> "Rainbow", VectorPoints -> 5, 
  VectorScale -> {0.03, .7, None}, 
  VectorStyle -> Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Rectangle[{-2, -.2}, {0, .2}], 
     Polygon[{{0, .5}, {Sqrt[3], 0}, {0, -.5}}]}]], 
 Graphics3D[{PointSize[.05], Black, Point[{0, 0, 0}], 
   PointSize[.04], Yellow, Point[{0, 0, 0}]}]]
```

[image]